# ionic cordova network ReferenceError: Connection is not defined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i created ionic project , installed ngCordova & cordova network information plugins , the network plugin works fine in browser but after installing  android 
platform & run app on mobile the plugin won't work anymore & show that error
[image: error screenshot]

please help , i really don't know what to do anymore

Comment: Please, edit and post your code.

Comment: i figured it out , plugins won't initialized untill device is ready ,controlller whicj was using cordova network plugin was called firest before run config